# Anaconda/IntelPython doesn't seem to offload to Xeon Ph 30

Tags: anaconda, intel-mkl, xeon-phi

```
    >>> import numpy
    >>> numpy.show_config()
    mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
        library_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/include']
    blas_mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
        library_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/include']
   blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/steph/anaconda3/envs/intel_py/include']
>>>
```

Which seems to indicate that I have the correct libraries.

My env settings are:

```
export MKL_MIC_ENABLE=1
export OFFLOAD_DEVICES=1,2
export OFFLOAD_ENABLE_ORSL=1
export MKL_HOST_WORKDIVISION=0,2
export MKL_MIC_WORKDIVISION=1
export MKL_MIC_1_WORKDIVISION=0.9
export MKL_MIC_2_WORKDIVISION=0.9
#export MKL_MIC_MAX_MEMORY=<value>
#export MKL_MIC_<number>_MAX_MEMORY=<value>
#For example: export MKL_MIC_0_MAX_MEMORY=2G
export MKL_MIC_REGISTER_MEMORY=1
#export MKL_MIC_RESOURCE_LIMIT=<value>
#For example: export MKL_MIC_RESOURCE_LIMIT=0.34
#export MIC_OMP_NUM_THREADS=<value>
#export MIC_<number>_OMP_NUM_THREADS=<value>
#For example: export MIC_0_OMP_NUM_THREADS=240
export OFFLOAD_REPORT=2
#For example: export OFFLOAD_REPORT=2
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/mic/coi/host-linux-release/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
#export MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/mic/coi/device-linux-release/lib:${MKLROOT}/lib/mic:${MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
#export MKL_MIC_THRESHOLDS_?GEMM="<N>,<M>,<K>"
#For example: export MKL_MIC_THRESHOLDS_?GEMM="2000,1000,500"
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16
export MIC_OMP_NUM_THREADS=236
export KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,compact,1,0
export MIC_KMP_AFFINITY=explicit,granularity=fine,proclist=[1-236:1]
export MIC_ENV_PREFIX=MIC_
```

Yet, when I run an fft.py, the mismc indicates no activity on the Phis.
There is also no offload report.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

StackOverflow wants me to add more to the question before I can post. I have all the details in the post, so this is just fluff to see if I can get this to post. What a silly little AI bot.

[image: mismc display]